# UML If parent class connect, do children also have to

Tags: uml, parent

I'm making a class diagram for my project documentation, and have come across this case. There are quite a few connections already in the diagram, and I would like to add on as little as possible. So I thought, if an (abstract) parent class has connections with some other class, it's children usually also keep up the same connection. Is it also the case with UML diagrams, or do I have to connect every chilren to the other class too?

Example image, of what I'm thinking would be possible:
[image]

Comment: Could you please reference the image's elements in your text and not use "some other class". I don't get your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Associations of a parent class with other classes are implicitly inherited by the subclasses. The inherited associations should not be drawn explicitly in the diagram.

It does not matter whether the parent class is abstract or not.

In your example diagram, Player and Enemy have associations with DrawingClass.

Be careful if you add multiplicities to the association ends. For example, if the association in your example is a 1:1 association, then each DrawingClass instance is connected either to a Player or to an Enemy (or, if Entity is not abstract, to a direct instance of Entity), not to both.

Answer (score -1):

The abstract (not interface) class *Entity* having let say the attribute *drawingClass* to *DrawingClass* the inheriting classes *Player* and *Enemy* also inherit the attribute *drawingClass*, so you do not have to repeat that attribute in them